# Hide line with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Currently I have the following fields displayed on a page:

Deliv​ery O​ption​s: Stand​ard S​hippi​ng

Gift ​Messa​ge: vbxcx​b

Deliv​ery D​ate:    12/06​/2013

Age V​erifi​catio​n:    No

They are generated server side upon completion of a form and the html looks like this:

```
<td class="ProductName" colspan="1">
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/basket-number-one/">Basket Number One</a>

    <table class="productAttributes" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Deliv&#8203;ery O&#8203;ption&#8203;s:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>Stand&#8203;ard S&#8203;hippi&#8203;ng</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Gift &#8203;Messa&#8203;ge:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>vbxcx&#8203;b</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Deliv&#8203;ery D&#8203;ate:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>12/06&#8203;/2013</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Age V&#8203;erifi&#8203;catio&#8203;n:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>No</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to hide the last line entirely, "Age Verification: No". I have tried the following but it ends up hiding everything except the first line, "Delivery Options...". Basically want to hide anything that contains "Age Verification and text following, in this case "No.":

```
<script>
    var age_html = $(".ProductName").html();
    $(".ProductName").html(age_html.replace("Age Verification", ""));
</script>​
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: OP said: << Basically want to hide anything that contains "Age Verification and text following, in this case "No.">>  @johnkavanagh Why have you removed this part of question, that makes my answer out of topic  ;)

Comment: I'm really sorry about that - I didn't think I had touched that part of the question (just tidied up the markup).  My mistake and should be resolved very shortly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to hide the last tr in table inside the `.ProductName` td

```
$('.ProductName table tr:last').hide();//or .remove() if you want to remove the td
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QFRk6/)

Comment: Perfect perfect! Thanks so much!! I thought it must be simpler than I was making it. Cheers! ~Susan

Answer (score 1):

First way..

You simply hide it serverside.

Second way..

you use `$('.productAttributes tr:last').hide()`,

see http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to accomplish this would be to assign that row of the table a class;

```
<tr class="age-verification">
    <td>
        <label>Age V&#8203;erifi&#8203;catio&#8203;n:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>No</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you can hide by class selection;

```
$('.productAttributes .age-verification').hide()
```

Comment: Might I ask, is it `.productAttributes age-verification` or `.productAttributes .age-verification` or `.productAttributes.age-verification` ?

Answer (score 0):

*<< Basically want to hide anything that contains "Age Verification and text following, in this case "No.">>*

To hide all rows with a cell containing "Age Verification":

```
$('td:contains("Age Verification")').parent().hide(); //or remove()
```

Comment: A. Wolff, I did already accept another answer that worked perfectly but wanted to try this out...for some reason it hides the entire table. Not sure why but wanted to mention it. Thank you for your response, Susan